# How could I change the points design?

Tags: xsim

[image]

IN xsim package, I want to get any new style for points -or remove the dash at least-.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}


\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[points=4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=4,bonus-points=10]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the `layouts` style and choose the appropriate template for exercises.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\loadxsimstyle{layouts}
\xsimsetup{exercise/template=runin}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[points=4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=4,bonus-points=10]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]